# MobileFirst iphone app is crashing with XenMobile Security

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When Wrapping MobileFist iphone ipa with XenMobile it is periodically Crashing for the users

The 
PA using the iOS developers team provisioning profile and have the customer wrap it into an MDX using their Apple Enterprise provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

No support can be given via Stack Overflow for such a problem. You need to go through the normal support chain, namely by opening a PMR (support ticket).